# Maximizing own window doesn't cover entire screen

Tags: c#, wpf, maximize-window

So this is my code for maximizing my own window:

```
private void maximizeWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Width = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
    this.Height = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height; 
}
```

This is how the code behaves:

[no Maximizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGQhE.png)

[with maximizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ1OY.png)

So the problem is that when I maximaze the window the screen gets maximized but te window is not positioned at the center I always have to move the screen upper left to see the entire screen.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to maximize a window, you should set the `WindowState` property to `WindowState.Maximized`:

```
private void maximizeWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Comment: well the problem is that I only want the workingarea to be maximazed not the entire window screen

Comment: What's the difference between the "workingarea" and the window and why do you then set `this.Width`?

Comment: the working area is the area which you "work" in. That means you see the windows bottom bar. Otherwise if you use maximized the entire window screen.

Comment: @plshm no, maximized windows do not cover Windows taskbar.

Comment: @mm8 it does at me I cant see the windows taskbar below as the entire screen gets covered.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer 2.0

By knowing that you want to make a window maximized without covering the taskbar, I recommended you to use a `WindowChrome`.

```
<Window x:Class="MejirdrituTeWarqoudear.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Width="540" Height="360">
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome CornerRadius="0" />
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <Window.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
            <Border Name="Bd">
                <AdornerDecorator>
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </AdornerDecorator>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized">
                    <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Padding" Value="8" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Template>
    <Border BorderThickness="8" BorderBrush="Teal" />
</Window>
```

By setting the `WindowState` to `Maximized`, the window will maximize like a normal window without covering the taskbar.

1. You may find that I add a `Template` for the `Window`. I write the template to add an extra padding when the window is maximized. If you remove it, you'll find that the window will lose some edges when it is been maximized. The value is `8` whatever your DPI value is.
2. `WindowChrome` help you to extend your client area UI into the non-client area. So you don't need to set the window transparent again. Remove `AllowsTransparency="True"` and `WindowStyle="None"` properties.

---

### Answer 1.0

If you only care for the primary screen:

```
// If you only cover the primary screen.
Left = 0.0;
Top = 0.0;
Width = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
Height = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
```

If you care for multiple screens:

```
// If you have more than one screen monitors, The code below covers the whole screen area.
Left = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenLeft;
Top = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenTop;
Width = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth;
Height = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight;
```

Comment: the probem is that my window taskbar dissapears  when I maximize it.

Comment: @plshm, So can I change my answer to another one using `WindowChrome`?

Comment: @plshm, I updated my answer using `WindowChrome`. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set location of the WPF window too. Add the follow as well as your code:

```
this.Left = 0;
this.Top = 0;
```

Comment: I don't have a attribute called Location in my MainWindow?

Comment: @plshm Sorry, my code for for winforms, try the update

Comment: **No**. You have a `WindowState` property, you do not need to set location/size. Moreover this is the _wrong_ MVVM approach: you should have a _command_ which change a property in the VM which is binded to the `WindowState` window property (possibly through a `ValueConverter`).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, it is wrong to involve view model into view-specific interactions

Comment: @ASh while it's true that _view_ things (such as this or to highlight something) should be kept into the view, it's still _wrong_ to use events for these things. The view _might_ contain its model but that does not excuse to avoid it (and this is especially true when logic in the view is more than a single flag then there is no reason to teach a suboptimal approach to unlearn later, maybe the other way around). For example: to maximize window is probably present as a button and as menu item, it should be disabled when window is already maximized and/or when it's fixed size).

Comment: You don't want to pollute all your code-behind code with this logic for every control which may trigger that action (and then again when handling keypresses). What's solution then? Use commands (and if you expose exactly the states of `WindowState` then you do not even need another property (otherwise the view _has_ its VM for the view state). In practice event handlers are (or should be) a rare exception in any non-trivial WPF app.